# Can I define a named query within the Shopify Graphiql app then call it from my PHP app?

Tags: graphql, shopify

In standard SQL, you can define stored procedures within the database admin, then call those procedures from your own app. At first sight Shopify GraphQL named queries are something very similar. I know how to define and run a named query within the Shopify Graphiql app, and also how to define and run a named query within my own PHP app. But I cannot find any way of defining a set of named queries within my store admin and then calling them from within my own app. Is this in fact possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you do inside your own App is your business! Of course you can create stored procedures and call them from your own App. Has nothing to do with Shopify or any restrictions they place on you. You don't use your store admin to define anything for any App, so I am not sure what you're trying there, but know this, you can indeed call named queries without trouble in your App.

Comment: Yes I understand how to define and use named queries within my app, but in SQL stored procedures are created and held within the database admin, with no reference to any particular app, and then apps can call on these stored procedures in place of putting explicit SQL into their code. I had hoped that GraphQL named queries could be used in a similar way, but maybe they can't.

Comment: I see. You want the convenience of stored procedures, called like GQL. My advice to you is to not mix-up two different technologies in that sense. If you want to call a stored procedure, call it! As usual. You do not need GQL for that.

Comment: OK, thanks. As I said originally, it seemed at first sight as if a GQL named query with arguments was much the same idea as an SQL stored procedure, but clearly it is not the same.

Comment: No. In GQL you can name something just like the old GOTO statement. It is not a shortcut way to calling a stored procedure! It is just a convenience to rename something so as to tag a portion of a call as an example, and re-use the query to get at something else, named something else!